# Base R on Power 9 CPU working (ppc64le architecture)?

Tags: r, powerpc, rstudio-server

There is an `r-base` [package available for the IBM Power9 CPU architecture (`ppc64le`) on Ubuntu Linux](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+package/r-base)
and I am wondering if R can really be used on this architecture beyond "does-it-run" experiments.

I did use this search engine to find the `r-base` package:
https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/open-source-pkgs/

Since this architecture is not officially supported by the R consortium: Does anybody successfully use R on this architecture in a production environment?

**Edit 1:** RStudio Server seems to be running at least within docker (but there is no official support by RStudio):

- [A Guide to Enable RStudio on IBM Power System](https://github.com/ppc64le/build-scripts/tree/master/rstudio)
- [Running RStudio Server on IBM/Power8](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/236077788)

**Edit 2:** I have found this [post at r-devel regarding a solved build failure](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2019-December/078801.html).

Comment: I don't really even know what Power9 CPU architecture is, but could you find a cloud provider with it, start an instance, install R and run some simple but challenging tests to put it through its paces?

Comment: @user5783745 Going the "hard way" testing all myself could work even though I am not sure if any cloud provider offers powerpc architectures directly (virtualisation is the goal). If nobody answers I will probably even buy a small machine for further tests...

Comment: Short update: I have found a description how to get a short-term no-cost access to Power hardware: https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/porting-guide/plan/

Comment: QEMU to emulate ppc64le architecture on an x86_64 is also possible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53259899/4468078

Comment: The [ubuntu build](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/436624506/buildlog_ubuntu-eoan-ppc64el.r-base_3.6.1-4_BUILDING.txt.gz) that ran the upstream tests. Seems to be some errors around Matrix as a module and some precision differences.

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't. I've only tested some very basic functionality in a qemu-emulated ppc setup and so far I can tell that basic things work correctly. As long as you are using `gcc` for compiling R packages from CRAN, I doubt there would be much incompatibilities as R packages do not typically use assembly or anything that could make it different in ppc. I foresee some things potentially going wrong (e.g. if a package assumes that char == signed char, which is true in x86 but not in ppc), but that you'd need to determine on a package-by-package basis.